# Java print SLDDRW(solidworks) file

Tags: java, printing, solidworks

A friend of mine want me, to make a simple program, to print some files.

Theese files are in the format .SLDDRW (Solidworks)

If the software is installed on the machine, are there then any simple way to print the files. I just no it's some kind of CAD program.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you mean by print: Getting a rendering of a CAD model on paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.SLDPRT - The Solidworks 3d model files

.SLDASM - The Solidworks 3d Assembly files, reference part and assembly files

.SLDDRW - The Solidworks 2d Drawing file, reference part and assembly files

If you have Solidworks installed you simply use the print command. There is even a batch printer where you can select a collection of files you want to print and it will print them all.

Comment: SLDPRT can also reference other part and assembly files.

Answer (score 0):

SolidWorks has an API.  You can use the API with C# or VB.  I can help with this program if needed.